# How to adjust custom android:button to fit inside View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button, android-checkbox

I have this checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/dish_dialog_radio_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/FRANCHISE_LOGO_SIZE"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/FRANCHISE_LOGO_SIZE"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/VIEW_MARGINS"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    />
```

and as you can see attribute `android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"`uses a custom drawable which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_unchecked_default"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_checked_default"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_unchecked_default"/>
</selector>
```

The problem is even though it is correctly displaying `ic_checked_default` when `android:state_checked="true"`and `ic_unchecked_default` when `android:state_checked="true"` it is appearing longer than the Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the sizes of the mipmap in the respective subfolder and it solved the problem